# Why is there a Bheem temple in Gorakhnath Mandir ,Gorakhpur?

Tags: temple, pandavas

There is a temple of Bheem also known as Bhimsena or Mahabali Bhim in the premises of Gorakhnath math in Gorakhpur. What is the importance of this temple? Give references from scriptures to validate your answer. Bheem is the Pandava who was very strong.

[image: Bheem image in gorakhnath temple]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to the story goes, **Pandavas** were performing '**Rajsuya Yagya**' to strengthen their kingdom. Thus, **Yudhisthir** sent **Bheem** to **Gorakhnath** to invite him.

But **Gorakhnath** was in samadhi at that time so **Bheem** had to wait. Meanwhile, **Bheem** laid down on the floor and fell asleep and when he woke up a pit was formed in the ground because of his body weight.
So, a temple was made in the memory of this story and it's an attraction now.

Comment: Just wondering how this is an answer from scripture